# Dynamically change the order of procedures called in SQL Server 2019

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a procedure in SQL Server that calls 6 other procedures (department names).

In a table I keep list of departments with numbers (total of 6 departments). The numbers of the departments gets updated daily and can drastically change the order that I need.

Is it possible to loop over the values of the table and change the order of the procedures called where the first procedure would be with the smallest number and the last procedure called will be the one with the largest number.

Example: current order of procedures call is:

```
EXECUTE InsertDep1Plan
EXECUTE InsertDep2Plan
EXECUTE InsertDep3Plan
EXECUTE InsertDep4Plan
EXECUTE InsertDep5Plan
EXECUTE InsertDep6Plan
```

The table keeps the numbers as this at the moment

```
DepName  |  DepNumber
---------+-----------
Dep1     |  123
Dep2     |  567
Dep3     |  413
Dep4     |  112
Dep5     |   76
Dep6     |   94
```

Now, is it possible to loop trough the table numbers ordered by `DepNumber` from smallest to largest and based on that to call the above procedures in that order?

I don't have to actually loop trough the table, I can also keep the numbers as @parameters and then compare the numbers and execute the procedures in that order.

Comment: Easy, just build a query to return the SPs in the correct order and dynamically execute them.

Comment: My first thought would be to use `string_agg()` to build the procedure names in the correct order as d-sql to be executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a SQL String to execute your procedures dynamically in the correct order.

An example of how you might do this is as follows:

```
create procedure proc1 as print 'proc1';
go
create procedure proc2 as print 'proc2';
go
create procedure proc3 as print 'proc3';
go


create table Departments(name varchar(5), seq int)
insert into departments select 'c1',10
insert into departments select 'c2',20
insert into departments select 'c3',30

declare @sql nvarchar(max)
select @sql=String_Agg(Concat('exec pro',name),';') within group(order by seq)
from Departments

exec sys.sp_executesql @sql
```

Executing the above builds a string *'exec proc1;exec proc2;exec proc3'* and then executes it; the output is

> proc1
>
> proc2
>
> proc3

Now change the requires ordering:

```
update departments set seq=40 where name='c2'
```

And re-run, the output is now

> proc1
>
> proc3
>
> proc2

Comment: thank you @Stu, I am marking this as answer as I find it a simple solution for me. Is it also possible to add parameters via String_Agg() or I need to find other way?

Comment: Yes absolutely it's possible, plenty of creative ways, anything you can execute directly as SQL in SSMS or from an application you can execute using `exec()`, look at the documentation for `sp_executesql` for how to add parameters, plenty of examples around and you can always ask another question for something specific.

Answer (score 1):

another option would be to store the procedure names in variables (@p1 being always the first and @p6 the last to be executed), assign the corresponding depnames to @p1…@p6 and exec @p1;…exec @p6; [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=12b8273b721d058db778c2c01223960b)

```
exec('create procedure procdep1 as select object_name(@@procid)');
exec('create procedure procdep2 as select object_name(@@procid)');
exec('create procedure procdep3 as select object_name(@@procid)');
exec('create procedure procdep4 as select object_name(@@procid)');

create table dep(depname varchar(20), depnumber int);
insert into dep(depname,depnumber)
values('dep1', 10),('dep2', 5),('dep3', 8),('dep4', 2);

select *
from dep
order by depnumber;


declare 
    @p1 nvarchar(150),
    @p2 nvarchar(150),
    @p3 nvarchar(150),
    @p4 nvarchar(150),
    @p5 nvarchar(150);

rexec:

select @p1=[1], @p2=[2], @p3=[3], @p4=[4]
from
(
select depname,row_number() over(order by depnumber)    as rn
from dep
) as d
pivot
(
max(depname) for rn in([1], [2], [3], [4])
) as p;

select @p1 = 'proc'+@p1, @p2 = 'proc'+@p2, @p3 = 'proc'+@p3, @p4 = 'proc'+@p4;

select concat(@p1,'->',@p2,'->',@p3,'->',@p4);

exec @p1;
exec @p2;
exec @p3;
exec @p4;

if not exists(select * from dep where depnumber < 0)
begin
update dep
set depnumber = depnumber - checksum(concat(depnumber,newid(),rand(depnumber)))%15 - 20;

goto rexec
end
```

Comment: I appreciate your way of doing the same thing differently